# How to style the tab bar in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

[image]

Can someone help to solve this out i used the react native 0.54.0, 
react-native-navigation, i use it on android device
thanks in advance.

this is the code for tab bar inside tab bar navigator.......

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
      var myTabs = TabNavigator(
       tabs:[
  Setting: {
  screen: SetttingScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: "Settings",

    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
      focused ? (
        <Image
          style={{ width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: "white" }}
          source={require("./app/components/Screens/Images/setting.png")}
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          style={{ width: 24, height: 24, tintColor: "white" }}
          source={require("./app/components/Screens/Images/setting.png")}
        />
      ),
    title: "Settings",

    headerTitleStyle: {
      alignSelf: "center",
      color: "white",
      fontWeight: "normal"
    },
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#333333" },
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: null
  }
}
```

and this is the code of tab option
now someone ans me thanks in advance
 `{
   tabBarPosition: "bottom",

```
animationEnabled: true,
swipeEnabled: false,
forceTitlesDisplay: true,

tabBarOptions: {
  pressColor: "blue",
  indicatorStyle: {
    opacity: 0
  },
  allowFontScaling: true,

  upperCaseLabel: false,
  showLabel: true,
  activeTintColor: "blue",
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: width * 0.022,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  showIcon: true,
  style: {
    // borderTopWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#221f1f",
    tabBarButtonColor: "#000",
    navBarTextFontSize: 34,
    forceTitlesDisplay: true,
    tabFontFamily: "Avenir-Medium"
  }
}
```

}`

Comment: can you post the code where you have used the tab bar?

Comment: codes are here @RajKumarN